# How do I setup a php script to run in crontab?

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to get a php script to run in crontab but when run in crontab I get an include error from php.

The crontab entry looks something like:

```
* * * * * php /path/sendEmail.php > /path/logs/sendEmail/sendEmail-`date +\%Y-\%m-\%H\ \%k:\%M:\%S`.log 2>&1 &
```

This creates the log files however inside the log files I get some php errors:

```
PHP Warning:  include_once(../../../lib/Database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/sendEmail.php on line 6

Warning: include_once(../../../lib/Database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/sendEmail.php on line 6
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '../../../lib/Database.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /path/sendEmail.php on line 6

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../../../lib/Database.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /path/sendEmail.php on line 6
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Database' not found in /path/sendEmail.php on line 9

Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in /path/sendEmail.php on line 9
```

When I run the command in the crontab entry I get the same errors in the log file. Now when I run `php sendEmail.php` in the terminal it works perfectly fine. Emails send out and everything. In the previous cases I get the errors (and the emails also don't send out).

Not sure how piping the output seems to change how the php script is run. Any ideas on how to get a php script to run as a cronjob?

Comment: You are having path problem from, the way you include the files are not safe `../../../lib/Database.php`

Comment: Is there a more proper way to include this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When cron starts the script its working directory is very unlikely to be the same directory in which your PHP script lives, so relative paths like `../../../lib/Database.php` are inadvisable, at least in their current form.

To the top of your script add:

```
define('__SCRIPT_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

And change your includes to:

```
include_once(__SCRIPT_ROOT . '/../../../lib/Database.php');
```

Now `__SCRIPT_ROOT` contains the absolute path to the script, and you can use that as a base to perform the relative pathing.